# Laravel count in blade file

Tags: laravel

This the code of my project.

**UPDATED**

**Controller**

```
 public function detailsGroup($id)
        {
            $users=Group::find($id);
            $attendance=Attendance::where('groupID',$id)->where('userAttendance','=','1')->get();
    
            return view("creator.group.groupdetails",['meeting'=>$meeting,'attendance'=>$attendance,'users;=>$users]);
        }
```

****Group.php****

```
public function creators()
        {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
        }
```

**User.php**

```
public function grp()
    {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class);
    }
```

**groupdetails.blade.php**

```
                          <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table id="" class="table">
                                    <thead>
                                         <tr>
                                            <th>No.</th>
                                            <th>Name</th>
                                            <th>Email</th>
                                            <th>Date Joined</th>
                                            <th>Attendance</th>
                                            <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    @foreach($users->creators as $user)
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                       
                                            <td>{{$loop->iteration}}</td>
                                            <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
                                            <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
                                            <td>{{$user->created_at}}</td>
                                            
                                            <@foreach($attendance as $at)
                                        @if($user->id == $at->userID)
                                        <td>{{$at->count() }}</td>
                                       @endif
                                      @endforeach
                                           
                                            <td><a href=""><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger .btn-{color}">Delete</button></a></td>
                                           
                                          </tr> 
                                        @endforeach
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
```

**blade page**
[image]

**database**

[image]

i want to count how many meeting that a user attended(`userAttendance='1'`).So, as shown in first picture, attendance for `userID=2` should be 4 because `userID=2` attend all meeting.

Comment: Your view shows user details, but you don't pass users to the view?

Comment: Are you sure that `->where('userID',$count)` is correct?

Comment: @Snapey, i already updated the code.

Comment: @Daniel, no i am not sure

Answer (score 0):

i think the third query is not working fine

what you are trying to do ?

$count is a collection because u are using `->get()` in the first query right?

now in the third query you are say `where('userID', $count)`

its should be `where('userID', $count->first()->id)`

or just use `->first()` in the first query then
use `where('userID', $count->id)`

Comment: i have changed it, nothing happened.

Comment: for each query add dump($query) and check the result

Comment: while fixing the code i managed to get the output as shown in the first picture, so what i need to do is to convert 13 13 13 13 to 4,do you have any idea to fix it?